# Heroku static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, production-environment

On Heroku, I am receiving a `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico` routing error.

Locally, I ***was*** receiving a `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/favicon.ico"):` routing error.

I fixed the local issue by setting `config.serve_static_assets =` to `TRUE` and running `rake assets:precompile`.

I have been unable to solve the issue on Heroku.  I pushed the updated version and ran `heroku run rake assets:precompile` to no avail.

This is driving me nuts ... a thumbnail icon is standing between me and a successful deployment.  Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Full heroku log dump:

```
2013-05-11T17:08:14.869656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-05-11T17:08:16.053848+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 44239`
2013-05-11T17:08:18.803969+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-11T17:08:18.804053+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2013-05-11T17:08:20.523845+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.523845+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2013-05-11T17:08:20.523845+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:312:in `depend_on'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.523845+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.13 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44239
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524353+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2013-05-11T17:08:20.523845+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- Digest (LoadError)
2013-05-11T17:08:20.524082+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
....
2013-05-11T17:08:21.668731+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**Update** Good lord, this was all due to a capital letter 'D' of require 'Digest' ... downcased and everything works.  That's a few hours of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: What if you put favicon.ico in public folder?

Comment: It is in my public folder

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you set - `config.serve_static_assets = false` and try to do `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` ? Further more is the following `config.assets.compile` set to `true`.

And another note I noticed you put your `favicon` in your public directory. I was able to set my favicon by doing the following in my `layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= home_title %></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        <link rel="icon" href="<%= image_path 'icon.ico' %>" type="image/ico" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<%= image_path 'icon.ico' %>" type="image/ico" />
    </head>
```

You will notice that my `icon.ico`. My `icon.ico` is in my app/assets/images directory.

Comment: No joy on setting to false and doing the rake.  config.assets.compile is set to FALSE.  I copy/pasted your html for the icon links and moved the file to app/assets/images ... no joy.

Comment: @DanShev you just said that you set  config.assets.compile is set to FALSE when initially you said you config.serve_static_assets = to TRUE. I think you may have just set the wrong thing to false. By default your `config.assets.compile` should be set to `true`. To clear things up my `environments/production.rb` looks like the following and so should yours. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5560804. What I have and then run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` and also include my `html`. If it gives you an error paste it here